# Omnet++: multidimensional vector as input

Tags: c++, omnet++

I managed to have one vector as input from omnetpp.ini as string and to be used as bool as per below,

```
//omnetpp.ini
**.setGate = "true false false false true false false"

//mynetwork.cc
bool MyQueue::gateState()
{
// reading input from omnetpp.ini as string
const char *vstr = par("setGate").stringValue();
std::vector<std::string> v = cStringTokenizer(vstr).asVector();

//Converting String Vector as bool Vector
bool mygate[6];

for (int x = 6; x>=0; x--){
    if (v[x] == "true")
        mygate[x] = true;
    else mygate[x] = false;
...
    };
```

I didn't find in Omnet++ manual any thing that allows me to have a multidimensional input as per below,

```
//omnetpp.ini
**.setGate = "true false false false true false false, 
              false false false false false false false,
              true false false false true false false"
```

**How can I overcome such a problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to read a multidimensional array. And using `cStringTokenizer` is probably the best idea. I propose the following code to read that array:

```
bool gatesBool[10][10]; // let's assume these dimensions

const char * tableStr = par("setGate").stringValue();
cStringTokenizer table(tableStr, ","); // a comma separates rows
int x = 0;
while (table.hasMoreTokens()) {
    cStringTokenizer row(table.nextToken(), " "); // a space separates elements
    int y = 0;
    while (row.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (strcmp(row.nextToken(), "true") == 0) {
            gatesBool[x][y] = true;
        } else {
            gatesBool[x][y] = false;
        }
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Notes:

1. You have to know in advance the dimensions of the array.
2. To write a string parameter in `omnetpp.ini` using many lines you should place backslash at the end of each line but the last, for example:

   ```
   **.setGate = "true true false,\
                 false false false"
   ```